# Different answers for `sizeof` for same object

Tags: c++, class, oop, sizeof

Why `sizeof` returns two different answers for a same object in this code?

```
class Test {
    public:
        int operator!() const {
            return sizeof(this);
        }
};
int main() {
    Test obj;
    std::cout << sizeof(obj) << " | " << !obj;
}
```

The output of code above is `1 | 8`

Comment: `this` has type `Test *`, not `Test`. It's a pointer to the current object, not the object itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to a current object of the class `Test`.. So the `operator !` returns the size of a pointer while `sizeof( obj )` is the size of the empty class `Test` or of an object of the class that may not be equal to zero in C++.

Change the operator as shown in the below program and you will get the expected result

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
    public:
        size_t operator!() const {
            return sizeof( *this );
            //             ^^^^^   
        }
};

int main() 
{
    Test obj;
    std::cout << sizeof(obj) << " | " << !obj;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 | 1
```

Comment: One more question, Why did you use `size_t` when returning size of that pointer?

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian because `sizeof()` returns `size_t` no matter what type you apply `sizeof()` on

Comment: @Slava Should we always use `size_t` when we want to store size of a structure like arrays, ints, ... ?

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian yes, because this is type specially created for this purpose https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t